# Where to search for vulnerabilities in a WordPress theme?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, wordpress

I have been doing research on a custom WordPress theme. I'm not very familiar with this CMS and how it works on the inside: where should I start my security analysis?  Should I look for SQL Injection (in the theme), XSS vulnerabilities, etc.?

I tried WP-SCAN and some other scanners, but I found nothing suspicious.

Comment: I'm assuming that the custom theme will not have known vulnerabilities and you need to test for them by scratch?

Comment: Thanks for the title correction, so yeah, where should I focus on finding unknown vulnerabilities?

Comment: Hm. That question is really, really broad. If you look at other known vulnerabilities in other themes, you might get an idea what to look for, but the question as asked is hard to answer in this format.

Comment: I'm asking for information of known weak places on wordpress themes. And basically, what to look for, as you said.